# Pressing the start button windows phone c # application is being closed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Pressing the start application button is being finalized, while passing by Application_Deactivated method is redirected to the method which identifies the exception Application_UnhandledException

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'*

closing the application.

I realized that the problem only occurs when I use the start button on a sub-screen for example:

Main -> Applications -> Query product

pressing the start button the application is closed, could not identify the source of the problem, can you help me?

**TEST PERFORMED**

I performed the following test:

I removed the whole page source and performed the procedure that the error occurred. And the problem still occurred.

Checks by backstack (this.NavigationService.BackStack) the open page are 2 more items in it taking the open page.

Believe possar be some command not performed as opening the pages separately the bug does not occur.

The bug occurs as follows:

Open main page; 
Open sales page for the main page; 
Open page by page product sales; 
Pressed start button;

Passes through Application_Deactivated, and after the error occurs in the App.xaml.cs Application_UnhandledException

Comment: can you perhaps show the code that you have it's very difficult to give an accurate answer or advice when we can't see what it is your have done initially..

Comment: Check the stack trace on the exception, WP definitely includes the method that threw the exception in the trace.

Comment: Call ToString() on the exception, [edit] your question and add what you get back.  The exception tells you exactly what you need to do.  Learn that.

Comment: changed with the test made

Answer (score 0):

I think, you've put an object that can't be serialized into either [page.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.state(v=vs.105).aspx) or [app.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.state(v=vs.105).aspx) dictionary. The OS tries to serialize your object upon deactivation, but fails with the exception and your app crashes.

P.S. You should be able to debug your app if you'll check "Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging" checkbox in the project settings (Debug tab), launch your app with the debugger, navigate to the problematic page, and press the start button on the device or simulator you're using.